Residual Function
In a time series with OLS regression curve Y-hat (rolling linear regression), and with n=20, what can I say about this transformation? This formula is similar to a differential dY/dt minus an integral of a data series.

The first term is the n-th residual of the OLS model. The second term is closely related to the SSE or MSE functions.  However, I have summed the raw residuals without squaring so this is basically a term that follows the trend in the residuals.

What is the variance of each term?  (1)
Can I use SSE or MSE to find (1)?
Does anybody recognize this kind of data transform? Related literature or topics? (3)

P.S.
The "1/4" in the second term is really just 5/n for my formula.
Thanks!

In what context did you find this transformation (where did it show up)? Could you maybe provide us with some more information about its relevancy or something else?

It's related to standard error estimation in rolling regression. This formula is used to analyze momentum in futures, options, and stock market data.
